# Twitter Typeahead.js with Flask Jinja2 Templating

Tags: flask, jinja2, typeahead.js

I am trying to define the template of typeahead.js through the flask application.

A solution I am looking for is either override the default(jinja2) template, or use the default to define a new template.

Updated:

This is what I have so far. any other value other than "value" does not work.

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    name: 'Search',
    local: {
        value: 'String1',
        tokens: ['1','one'],
        name: 'StringTest'
    },
    template: '<p>Template {{value}}{{name}}</p>', // Only shows "Template String1"
    engine: Hogan
});
```

Here is what my template looks like

```
<script src='http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.js'</script>   
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/builds/2.0.0/hogan-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/search.js"></script> // Hard coded to see if it works..
```

Comment: I updated. Hopefully my question is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there are several ways you can achieve what you want. The easiest way would be separate the typeahead.js code into another file.

So in your main template you can have:

```
<script src="/js/typeahead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prefetch_url = '{{ url_for('jsonData') }}'; // not so sure if you need the quote here?
</script>
<script src="/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

... your template code ...
```

And in the `main.js` file, you can init the typeahead.js as normal:

```
$('#search').typeahead.js({
    name: 'Search',
    prefetch: prefetch_url,
    template: ... ,// a normal Hogan template
    engine: Hogan
});
```

Since Flask doesn't process the static files like `main.js`, Jinja2 won't conflict with Hogan syntax and you can do whatever you want there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Would I have to incorporate node.js or still include hogan from a link? Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't know about nodejs part but I would recommend you include the reference as normal.

Comment: I have, but I can only reference value via templating. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{% raw %}` Jinja template tag to escape the `{{}}` as mentioned in the [Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escaping):

```js
$('#search').typeahead({
    name: 'Search',
    local: {
        value: 'String1',
        tokens: ['1','one'],
        name: 'StringTest'
    },
    template: {% raw %}'<p>Template {{value}}{{name}}</p>'{% endraw %},
    engine: Hogan
});
```